# How can I give the filename of current buffer automatically when I execute 'compile' command in Emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, compilation, keymapping

As you already know, we can see 'make -k' command when we execute 'M-x compile' in emacs c++ mode.

But, now I'm studying some boost libraries, so I must frequently compile just single file after writing a example code.
So, for convenience, I've been doing this like below.

```
(1) make an alias in shell init file for g++ compile command.
    alias c="g++ -g -Wall -O0 -std=c++11"
(2) map 'M-x compile' command to Function Key F9 in .emacs
    (global-set-key [f9] 'compile)
(3) write c++ code
(4) press F9 and modify filename to current open file
```

For example, you can see 'Compile command: c vvv.cpp' in the below screen shot. 
(This screen shot is just a simple code that I made for this question. 
'c' is alias for compile command and options)
But, this open filename is actually 'vector1.cpp', so 'vvv.cpp' should be automatically replaced by 'vector1.cpp'.

[image]

I think this is not bad.
But, I'd like to find a way that I don't have to modify the current filename.
"Just press F9 and RET, then the current file will be compiled." This is exactly what I want.

Is there any better idea or way I can do like this?
Or plz let me know your nice compiling way for a minimal key pressing. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/) has a nice section explaining how you can customize the `compile` command: [Compile Command](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand)

In your case, you could add a hook to the c++ mode to define the `compile-command` variable as you need. Following the example on the wiki:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
         (format "g++ -g -Wall -O0 -std=c++11 %s" (buffer-name)))))
```

Adding this snippet to your `.emacs` should do the trick.